# Mostrar datos Consulta Mysql en tabla PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

Tengo un formulario muy simple en donde solicito ingresar el RUT de un funcionario para consultar por los registros ingresados en la tabla funcionarios.
He realizado consulta directamente en mi base de datos por un Rut en particular y validé que tiene varios registros ingresados.

En el formulario ingreso un RUT, la consulta se realiza correctamente a la base de datos y recorro dicha consulta con un While, logrando mostrar datos en la tabla, pero mi problema esta en que solo he logrado que se muestre un solo registro, y no crea las diferentes filas para mostrar toda la información en la tabla.
Espero que alguien me pueda orientar a resolver esto.

```
<?php 
   include "conexion.php";

   if(!empty($_POST))
   {
     $rut = $_POST['rut'];

     $query = mysqli_query($conection,"SELECT rut, nombres, apellidos, carrera, 
     nombre_establecimiento, fecha_ingreso
     FROM funcionario
     WHERE semestre = 2 and estado = 1 and rut = '$rut'");

     $result = mysqli_num_rows($query);

     if($result > 0)
     {
        while ($data = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) 
        {
            $rut = $data['rut'];
            $nombres = $data['nombres'];
            $apellidos = $data['apellidos'];
            $fecha_ingreso = $data['fecha_ingreso'];
            $nombre_establecimiento = $data['nombre_establecimiento'];
        }
     }
  }
?>

 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="./img/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"/>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
 </head>
 <body>
   <section id="container">
      <div class="form_register_estudiante">
         <form action="" method="post">
            <label for="rut">Rut</label>
            <input type="text" name="rut" id="rut">
            <BR>
            <button type="submit" class="btn_new_cons">Buscar</button>
            <button type="reset" class="btn_new_cons">Limpiar</button>

            <table>
              <tr>
                 <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%;">RUT</th>
                 <th class="text-center" style="width: 20%;">NOMBRES</th>
                 <th class="text-center" style="width: 20%;">APELLIDOS</th>
                 <th class="text-center" style="width: 40%;">ESTABLECIMIENTO</th>
                 <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%;">FECHA INGRESO</th>
              </tr>
                
              <tr>
                <td><?php echo $rut?></td>
                <td><?php echo $nombres?></td>
                <td><?php echo $apellidos?></td>
                <td><?php echo $nombre_establecimiento?></td>
                <td><?php echo $fecha_ingreso?></td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </form>
      </div>
    </section>
   </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que estás sobreescribiendo las variables dentro del `while`. Tienes que concatenar para que salgan todas las filas. Eso implica como es lógico trasladar la parte de las filas al bloque donde está el `while`. En ese sentido me permito implementar algunas mejoras como el uso de `sprintf`, haciendo el código menos verboso.

Por ejemplo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="./img/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"/>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
     <section id="container">
        <div class="form_register_estudiante">
          <form action="" method="post">
            <label for="rut">Rut</label>
            <input type="text" name="rut" id="rut">
            <BR>
            <button type="submit" class="btn_new_cons">Buscar</button>
            <button type="reset" class="btn_new_cons">Limpiar</button>
<?php
   include "conexion.php";

   if(!empty($_POST))
   {
     $rut = $_POST['rut'];

     $query = mysqli_query($conection,"SELECT rut, nombres, apellidos, carrera,
     nombre_establecimiento, fecha_ingreso
     FROM funcionario
     WHERE semestre = 2 and estado = 1 and rut = '$rut'");

     $result = mysqli_num_rows($query);

     if($result > 0)
     {
        #Variable para concatenar toda la tabla 
        $table='
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                        <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%;">RUT</th>
                        <th class="text-center" style="width: 20%;">NOMBRES</th>
                        <th class="text-center" style="width: 20%;">APELLIDOS</th>
                        <th class="text-center" style="width: 40%;">ESTABLECIMIENTO</th>
                        <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%;">FECHA INGRESO</th>
                        </tr>';

        #Plantilla para las filas
        $tr="<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td></tr>";
        while ($data = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
        {
            #Concatenamos cada fila/columna a la tabla
            $table.=sprintf($tr,
                                $data['rut'],
                                $data['nombres'],
                                $data['apellidos'],
                                $data['fecha_ingreso'],
                                $data['nombre_establecimiento']
                            );
        }
        $table.="</table>";
        #Imprimimos la tabla
        echo $table;
     }
  }
?>
            </form>
        </div>
    </section>
   </body>
</html>
```

#### Advertencia sobre la seguridad

Tu actual código es altamente vulnerable a ataques de *inyección SQL*. Considera usar consultas preparadas adecuadamente para prevenir ese gravísimo riesgo.

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder, estoy revisando el código ya que al parecer hay un problema y no me permite ingresar a la pagina y vuelve al inicio.

Comment: Logré identificar lo que faltaba y me funcionó su código, una vez mas agradecido por su ayuda.